# Is it legal to move the .str() member of a stringstream?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue

Consider the following example:

```
#include <sstream>
template <typename T>
inline std::string to_string(T const & op) {
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << op;
    return result.str();
}
```

If I was to return *result*, instead of *result.str()* it would automatically become an rvalue. Not so the string contained in in result (I assume). My expectation is that it is copied and the copy returned as an rvalue.

So my question here is, is it legal to:

```
return std::move(result.str());
```

I would assume it is, expecting the stream to be left with a valid, empty string. But I do not feel certain enough to actually do it.

Comment: Calling `std::move(e)` in a return statement is an anti-pattern. The returned expression is implicitly treated as an rvalue anyway and using `std::move` inhibits copy-elision.

Comment: @TartanLlama aren't you oversimplifying? What if there was a function "std::string std::ostringstream::str() &&", wouldn't the best way to leave the function a "return std::move(result).str();"?

Comment: @kamikaze Yeah, as Baum says I was referring to the pattern where all you have in your return statement is `std::move(e)`, where `e` is some expression.

Comment: @kamikaze `return move(e)` (bad) != `return move(e).smth()` (might (very rarely) make sense). (Partially reposted because of edit.)

Comment: should it be okay to std::move to a parameter to a function?

`void some_func (std::string &output) {
     std::stringstream ss;
     .......
     output = std::move(ss.str());
  }`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::ostream::str` indeed returns a copy of the internal string. So the move is legal, but it makes no sense as `result.str()` is an rvalue anyway and thus the `std::move` does nothing useful. If anything, it hinders RVO, so don't do it. (As [@TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496161/tartanllama) correctly pointed out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726798/is-it-legal-to-move-the-str-member-of-a-stringstream#comment59128590_35726798), *"Don't move the return value"* holds true in general, not just when returning rvalues.)

In particular, the `std::move` does not affect the internal string object of the stream.

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy. For some reason I thought it returns a reference.

Comment: @kamikaze When in doubt or to double check consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)

Comment: @kamikaze That's what we have [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) for. ;)

Comment: Though if you wanted to prevent return value optimization and copy elision for whatever reason, this would be the way to do it.